# Trying to create custom accordian in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I was trying to create custom Accordion it is created but problem is when i click first panel all remaining accordion panel were open i don't what to do how can acquire that functionality and i want to change plus icon into minus icon when i click on panel and vice vers
 your help will be appreciated.

Code is given Below

Html

```
<div ng-app ="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myController">
<h2>Accordion</h2>
<div  ng-repeat ="accd in accordion">
  <button class="accordion accordion-icon" id="aac1" ng-click="showAccordianPanel($event)">{{accd}}</button>
<div class="panel" ng-show="showContent">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Js

```
<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    myApp.controller("myController",function($scope){
    $scope.accordion =["section 1","section 2","section 3"]
    $scope.showContent=false;
    $scope.showAccordianPanel =function(ev){
    ev.target.showContent = true;
    $scope.showContent=!$scope.showContent
    } 
    })

</script>
```

Css

```
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd; 
}
.accordion-icon:before{
  content: '\002B';
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.minus-icon:before{
      content: "\2212";
      float: right;
}
div.panel {
    padding: 4px 20px;
   /*  display: none; */
    background-color: #ddd;
     margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

And the js Fiddle is :https://jsfiddle.net/wL9ncvax/3/

Comment: check this `https://jsfiddle.net/49g4qufu/`

Comment: Thanks a ton  Buddy it works  one more click on panel plus sign should change minus sign

Comment: Check the updated answer https://jsfiddle.net/49g4qufu/1/. Will post this as an answer so that you can accept

Comment: Thanks a ton buddy i appreciate for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of updating the `showContent` property in the global scope(ie, scope of the controller) update only in the corresponding pane scope inside the iterator(ng-repeat).

updated controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller("myController",function($scope){
    $scope.accordion =["section 1","section 2","section 3"]
    $scope.showContent=false;
    var lastActivePanelScope;
    $scope.showAccordianPanel =function(ev, itemScope){
        itemScope.showContent = !itemScope.showContent;

        if (lastActivePanelScope) {
            if (lastActivePanelScope !== itemScope) {
                lastActivePanelScope.showContent = false;
            }
        }

        if (itemScope.showContent) {
            lastActivePanelScope = itemScope;
        }    
    } 
});
```

Add `ng-class` on the button to toggle between plus and minus icons

```
<button class="accordion" ng-class="showContent ? 'minus-icon': 'accordion-icon'"
        id="aac1" 
        ng-click="showAccordianPanel($event, this)">{{accd}}</button>
```

working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/49g4qufu/1/)

Answer (score 0):

All you need is `showContent` as an array instead of single variable. Hence,

```
$scope.showContent = [false, false, false];
$scope.showAccordianPanel = function(index) {
  $scope.showContent[index] = !$scope.showContent[index]
}
```

And, `ng-repeat` would be like,

```
<div ng-repeat="accd in accordion">
  <button ... ng-click="showAccordianPanel($index)">{{accd}}</button>
  <div class="panel" ng-show="showContent[$index]">
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice, how I passed `$index` in `ng-click` function to open only clicked accordion and not others.

[**working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4hzrpayv/2/)

Comment: suppose there is situation we have requirement of 10 -20 accordions then is this the efficient way of writing code  then i have to write 20 times false  statement

Comment: @MujtabaHussainBhat yes this should not have any significant performance impact till you have accordions in thousands or even more than that